# Как убрать меню из Win32 окна создаваемого в Visual Studio;

Tags: visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

Как убрать меню из стандартного приложения Win32, которое создается средой Visual Studio 2010.

[image]

Используя стандартную функцию CreateWindow пишу так:

```
hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_POPUP,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

`WS_POPUP` - стиль, означающий временное окно, у него не должно быть меню, однако как видно на скрине, окно создается с меню.
Как добиться того, что бы меню не было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря лень создавать. Если не ошибаюсь в функции CreateWindow в 9 параметре указывается меню. Замени значение на 0 и меню должно пропасть. Параметр HMENU hMenu.

Comment: Там NULL стоит изначально) Я косячно вопрос задал, вот переделал как подабает)

Comment: Тогда ноль вот сюда: в MyRegisterClass(), wcex.lpszMenuName должна быть равна нулю.

Comment: Это афигенно) Спасибо большое)

Comment: И из ресурсов еще меню удалить